# eval function returns invalid name error, but only some of the time

Tags: excel, vba

I have a vba function which evaluates a string:

```
Public Function eval(s As String) As Variant
    eval = Evaluate(s)
End Function
```

It works fine, some of the time. However, sometimes after I've made changes to an unrelated part of the workbook any cells which use this formula evaluate to an invalid name error. The error disappears when the cell is re-evaluated (i.e. I click in the cell and press enter). Strangely, just by re-evaluating one of the cells with an error corrects all other cells with this error.

I can't figure out what's causing this. All help greatly appreciated.

An example of how I'm using the function is below:

```
=IF(ISTEXT(max_vertical_load),
          EVAL(INDIRECT(max_vertical_load)),
                    max_vertical_load)
```

Answer (score 2):

You're using the default `Application.Evaluate` form, which uses `ActiveSheet` as the evaluation context. So results may depend on which sheet is active when the UDF runs.

If you need the string evaluated in a specific worksheet context then use the `Worksheet.Evaluate` form (assuming there's a specific worksheet involved).

Answer (score 0):

To apply this formula the followings have to be taken in consideration.

INDIRECT (input)

If input is a cell reference (input = D2) it works as an indirect address.

If input is a string which is a cell reference (input = "D2") then it returns the cell content.

[image]

[image]

If a name is used for reference: (Cell A4 is named to "refcell")

[image]

Based upon this the formula in the cell

[image]

Here the UDF is placed in a Module and is:

```
Function myfunc(s)
myfunc = Evaluate(s)

End Function
```